# package and class design in java and access granularity

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm working in a team, we decided to divide the in groups so every group would deliver a jar file that would run in different JVM's. In defining 'Class A' in my group i found that other groups would access just some properties and setters, at runtime objects of type A are stored in a cache and retrieved by the rest of the team. To provide the necessary granularity i decided to create two jars:

A1.jar that should be used by the rest of the team and would include the Class A that would be stored and retrieved from the cache.

A2.jar that would contain both a B class derived from A and my business code, this jar wouldn't be used by the rest of the team but it would be accesed by some SOA interfaces.

The i moved the setters and properties not accesible by the rest of the team to class B but i've got some doubts.

What if some group needs different access to Class A (say they can set some property others cannot)?

Is there any pattern to deny access to some properties in a class based upon the package of the user of the class, aside from the protected, public, private keywords?

p.d: by group i mean some group of persons of the development team which delivers some jar file, the constituion of the groups reflects the logical business, when i say 'access' i mean static access to the code via the private/protected/public/package keywords, by any mean i meant any dynamic access related to runtime properties.

Please, excuse my english

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an odd usage of inheritance and modules. I would instead publish an API that is an interface or a set of interfaces, and possibly a factory.

Comment: I simplified the class hierarchy but A1.jar is indeed an API used by the rest of team, they interact with my business code via WS calls using that API.